# How do I iterate through a directory in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, filesystems, directory, common-lisp

I'm using OpenMCL on Darwin, and I'd like to do something like:

```
(loop for f in (directory "somedir")
  collect (some-per-file-processing f))
```

But I can't get `directory` to return anything other than `NIL`, and I can't seem to find any good explanation online (other than "its different for each system").

Any pointers?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does your pathname specification contain a wildcard? Common Lisp's pathname stuff is somewhat hard to grasp at first - at least for me it was... As the [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dir.htm#directory) states on the `directory` function:

> If the pathspec is not wild, the
>   resulting list will contain either
>   zero or one elements.

In order to have your pathname include a wildcard, you might try the make-pathname function, like

```
(directory (make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "srv" "hunchentoot") :name :wild :type "lisp"))
```

Or even

```
(directory (make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "srv" "hunchentoot") :name :wild :type :wild))
```

I found the [CL-FAD](http://www.cliki.net/CL-FAD) library a great help for dealing with pathnames and the file system. In particular, its [`list-directory`](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/#list-directory) function might be easier to use than the plain standard `directory` function.

Comment: Yep worked for me - (directory "pathname") returned NIL, where (directory "pathname/*.*") gave me expected results.

Comment: You need only files with names containing a dot?

Comment: Weird huh? I'm actually after .h and .cpp files, but "pathname/*" returns NIL.

Comment: Might have something to do with the way Lisp merges "incomplete" the pathnames with some defaults. As your "/path/*" does only contain a wildcard for the name, but not for the type, I guess the CCL simply takes the type to look for from the *default-pathname* or something. I have been bitten often enough by the unwarranted assumption, that a pathname/pattern valid in a shell was also a valid/equivalent Lisp pathnames

Answer (score 32):

There are basically two ways to specify pathnames:

**Using strings**

Strings are obviously depending on the platform: Unix syntax vs. Windows syntax for example.

```
"/Users/foo/bar.text"  is a valid pathname
"/Users/foo/*/foo.*"   is a valid pathname with two wildcards
```

You can create a pathname object from a string:

```
? (pathname "/Users/bar/foo.text")
#P"/Users/bar/foo.text"
```

The `#p` above assures that a pathname object (and not a string) is created, when you read it back.

```
? #P"/Users/bar/foo.text"
#P"/Users/bar/foo.text"
```

So, internally Common Lisp works with pathname objects, but it lets you use normal strings and makes pathname objects from them if needed.

When Common Lisp sees a pathname that has not all components specified (for example the directory is missing), then it fills in the components from the pathname object that is the value of the variable `*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS*` .

With the function DESCRIBE you can look at the components of a pathname (here *Clozure CL*):

```
? (describe (pathname "/Users/bar/*.text"))
#P"/Users/bar/*.text"
Type: PATHNAME
Class: #<BUILT-IN-CLASS PATHNAME>
TYPE: (PATHNAME . #<CCL::CLASS-WRAPPER PATHNAME #x3000401D03BD>)
%PATHNAME-DIRECTORY: (:ABSOLUTE "Users" "bar")
%PATHNAME-NAME: :WILD
%PATHNAME-TYPE: "text"
%PHYSICAL-PATHNAME-VERSION: :NEWEST
%PHYSICAL-PATHNAME-DEVICE: NIL
```

**Using the Lisp functions creating pathname objects**

`MAKE-PATHNAME` is the function and it takes a few keyword arguments to specify the components.

Sometimes it is also useful to create a new pathname based on an existing one:

```
(make-pathname :name "foo" :defaults (pathname "/Users/bar/baz.text"))
```

**If you use the function `DIRECTORY` it is useful to use a pathname with wildcards.** `DIRECTORY` then will return a list of matching pathnames. The name `DIRECTORY` is slightly misleading, since `DIRECTORY` does not list the contents of a directory, but lists the matching pathnames for (usually) a pathname with wildcards. The wildcards can match a sequences of characters in components like `/foo/s*c/list*.l*`. There is also the wild card `**` , which is used to match parts of a directory hierarchy like  `/foo/**/test.lisp` , which matches all files `test.lisp` under the directory `foo` and its subdirectories.

```
(directory "/Users/foo/Lisp/**/*.lisp")
```

Above should return a list of all `lisp` files in `/Users/foo/Lisp/` and all its subdirectories.

To return the `.c` files in a single directory use:

```
(directory "/Users/foo/c/src/*.c")
```

Note that `DIRECTORY` returns a list of *pathname* objects (not a list of strings).

```
? (directory
    (make-pathname
      :name "md5"
      :type :wild
      :directory '(:absolute "Lisp" "cl-http" "cl-http-342" "server")))
(#P"/Lisp/cl-http/cl-http-342/server/md5.lisp"
 #P"/Lisp/cl-http/cl-http-342/server/md5.xfasl")
```

Above uses a pathname object that is created by `MAKE-PATHNAME`. It returns all the files that match `/Lisp/cl-http/cl-http-342/server/md5.*` .

This is the same as:

```
(directory "/Lisp/cl-http/cl-http-342/server/md5.*")
```

which is shorter, but depends on the Unix pathname syntax.

Answer (score 9):

The modern Common Lisp library implementing directory listing is [IOLIB](http://common-lisp.net/project/iolib/).

It works like this:

```
CL-USER> (iolib.os:list-directory "/etc/apt")
(#/p/"trusted.gpg~" #/p/"secring.gpg" #/p/"trustdb.gpg" #/p/"sources.list"
 #/p/"sources.list~" #/p/"apt-file.conf" #/p/"apt.conf.d" #/p/"trusted.gpg"
 #/p/"sources.list.d")
```

Note that no trailing slash or wildcards are required.  It is very robust and can even process file names with incorrectly encoded unicode characters.

Differences compared to CL-FAD:

- The objects you get are IOLIB file paths, a replacement for CL's pathnames which is closer what the underlying OS does.
- IOLIB implements its routines using CFFI, so it works the same on all Lisp implementations (provided IOLIB has a backend for the operating system), in contrast to CL-FAD, which tries to abstract over the implementation's DIRECTORY function with all its quirks.
- In contrast to CL-FAD, iolib deals correctly with symlinks (one major issue with CL-FAD that makes it virtually unusable on platforms other than Windows IMHO).

Answer (score 3):

I'll add an example that works for me, for the sake of a code snippet. I use [osicat](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/osicat/manual/osicat.html#Directories) (similar to cl-fad) and [str](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str).

**edit**: also with `uiop:directory-files`. str:contains? could be done with `search`.

```
;; searching for "ref".
(setf *data-directory* "~/books/lisp")
(remove-if-not (lambda (it)
                   (str:contains? "ref" (namestring it)))
                (osicat:list-directory *data-directory*))
```

returns

```
(#P"~/books/lisp/common-lisp-quick-reference-clqr-a4-booklet-all.pdf"
 #P"~/books/lisp/common-lisp-quick-reference-clqr-a4-consec.pdf"
 #P"~/books/lisp/commonLisp-interactive-approach-reference-buffalo.pdf")
```

It can certainly be improved my a proper use of wildcards. However that's a snippet you can use right now : )

References:

- https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#files-and-directories
- https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/files.html