# How to invoke a function within a for loop in Lisp?

Tags: for-loop, lisp, common-lisp

I have 25 text files in my folder to be tested. But I don't want to write code for 25 files which means that it is 25 rows to test those files.

```
(myfunc "myfiles/txtfile1.txt")
(myfunc "myfiles/txtfile2.txt")
...
```

How can I use a for loop to invoke this function? Like the example code below. Sorry for my poor English

```
(loop for x from 1 to 25
  do ((myfunc "myfiles/txtfile~a.txt" x))
) 
)
```

Comment: ` do ((myfunc "myfiles/txtfile~a.txt" x))` beware, the two following parenthesis are wrong.

Comment: Here's a primer on `format` directives: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#structure-of-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some functional approach

```
(mapcar function (directory (merge-pathnames wildcard path)))
```

`mapcar` - applies `function` to the provided list of arguments generated by `directory`. `function` has to accept only one argument.

Working Example

*61650326.lisp*

```
;;;; File     : 61650326.lisp
;;;; Modified : <2020-5-08 Fri 08:51:12 BST>
;;;; URL      : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650326

(defparameter *user-path* "t/user/myfiles/")
(defparameter *wildcard* "*.txt")
(defparameter *function* 'type-of)

(defun map-on-files (path wildcard function)
    "Map FUNCTION on a list of files found under PATH WILDCARD."
    (mapcar function (directory (merge-pathnames wildcard path))))

(format t "~{~A~%~}" (map-on-files *user-path* *wildcard* *function*))
```

Generating some files for test purpose:

```
~$: mkdir -p t/user/myfiles
~$: for i in $(seq 10); do mktemp -p t/user/myfiles/ --suffix=.txt; done
t/user/myfiles/tmp.S4wKkJ85sq.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.j3XeT2hneq.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.mut6GLhlaT.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.1l0I5oGDaR.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.hBpvOfarye.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.m1WfmZxrU8.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.o6QbvjXMh9.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.6CmPvWf7GO.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.ZNWcaymY0g.txt
t/user/myfiles/tmp.JfUQ4cW0dD.txt
```

And Run code snippet

```
~$: sbcl --script 61650326.lisp
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
PATHNAME
```

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I want to do but I am new on Lisp. My path is "user/myfiles/textfile.txt" can you give me an example from this path how I can read all files in this folder?

Comment: @JuanRodre I've extended answer with more explicit example

Comment: Thank you so much @Hellseher

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use the `format` function ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm#format)):

```
(loop for x from 1 to 25
      do (myfunc (format nil "myfiles/txtfile~a.txt" x)))
```

Since all the files are in a directory, you could also give a look to the `directory` predefined function ([manual](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dir.htm), [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403717/how-do-i-iterate-through-a-directory-in-common-lisp)).

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the digit at the end of the filename with format:

(loop for x from 1 to 25
  do (myfunc (format nil "myfiles/txtfile~a.txt" x)) )